# How to solve "undefined control sequence" error for "\newword" in Latex?

Tags: latex, tex-live

I'm using Texlive 2018, and I'm going to run a simple code. I got the error for commands like: "\newword", "\newacronym", "\gls", that

```
Undefined control sequence. \newword
```

I'm wondered why the same code can be run on others system. Is there anything I haven't done to run my code properly?

Comment: Do you properly include the glossaries package? If yes and if you have a full texlive, you should have \newglossary and \gls. But I do not think \newword is a standard macro in any package...

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?